# Passing command line arguments to a Perl program run using Padre

Tags: perl, padre

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to a Perl program you are running from the Padre menu ("Run->Run Script")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Tools->Preferences->"Language - Perl5", set "Script arguments" and save.

Or under Tools->Preferences->Advanced, see "run_script_args_default".  Set a value, and save.

Either way they do the same thing.  You can also use the "Interpreter Arguments" field to set flags for the Perl interpreter.

Comment: Great. Any idea how to set the script execution directory (i.e., if my args are relative paths, I want to be able to tell Padre "where" the script was invoked, which is not necessarily at its save directory)?